# error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aot/hint/TypeHint$Builder

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

Estoy creando un api con spring boot, Intellij Idea y maven he hecho varias modificaciones para poder usar diferentes dependencias y despues de arreglar varios errores me sale el siguiente error:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.5:run (default-cli) @ curso ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []
2022-12-07 19:23:32.729 ERROR 10976 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aot/hint/TypeHint$Builder
    at org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext.<clinit>(GenericApplicationContext.java:114) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext$Factory.create(AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:220) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.ApplicationContextFactory.lambda$static$0(ApplicationContextFactory.java:47) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createApplicationContext(SpringApplication.java:569) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at com.cursojava.curso.CursoApplication.main(CursoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.aot.hint.TypeHint$Builder
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
```

Tengo las siguientes clases e interfaces creadas.

UserDAOImp:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

UserDAO:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

UserController:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agregue más dependencias a mi proyecto como lo son las de JPA, MySQL, Lombook, anexo mi pom para mas detalles

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.cursojava</groupId>
    <artifactId>curso</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>curso</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.30</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Y mi archivo application.properties agregue lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por mi parte aun no logro encontrar el error me pueden ayudar por favor.

Answer (score 0):

El error está diciendo que falta la clase "TypeHint$Builder".

Agrégasela al POM.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: yo me encontré con este mismo error por casualidad pero yo si tengo spring aop en el classpath.... tal vez en ciertas versiones de hace algunos años no exista la clase aun

Comment: Ya agregue la dependencia y aun sigue saltando el error